# javascript onclick event in elements loop [no jQuery]

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

i have a problem in javascript **[NOT JQUERY]**;
i want to create slideshow, for each slide i create  that want when user click on it, jump to that slide...

```
var images = $('#images img'), image;

for(var i = 0; image = images[i]; i++)
{

    var a = document.createElement('span');
    a.onclick = function(){
        var img = image;
        removeClass();
        console.log(img);
        img.className = 'active';
    }

    $('#nav')[0].appendChild(a);

}
```

in above code i am trying remove active class name from slides and then add active to related slide, but i don't know how can get that slide in span.onclick function

My Code:

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<head>

    <title>Welcome</title>
    <style>
        #images {position:relative;}
        #images img {position:absolute;top:0;right:0;opacity:0;transition:all 0.8s;-webkit-transition:all 0.8s;}
        .active {opacity:1!important;}
        #nav span {display:inline-block;width:12px;height:12px;background:red;border:1px solid #CCC;cursor:pointer;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="images">
        <img src="1.jpg" class="active" />
        <img src="2.jpg" />
        <img src="3.jpg" />
        <img src="4.jpg" />
        <img src="5.jpg" />
        <img src="6.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="nav"></div>
</body>


<script>

    function $(id)
    {
        return document.querySelectorAll(id);
    }

    function removeClass(){
        var images = $('#images img'), image;
        for(var i = 0; image = images[i]; i++)
        {
            image.className = '';
        }
    }


    var images = $('#images img'), image;

    for(var i = 0; image = images[i]; i++)
    {

        var a = document.createElement('span');
        a.onclick = function(){
            var img = image;
            removeClass();
            console.log(img);
            img.className = 'active';
        }

        $('#nav')[0].appendChild(a);

    }

    function start(){
        return setInterval(function()
        {
            var current = $('.active')[0];
            var next = current.nextElementSibling;
            if(!next){
            console.log('noefds f as');
                next = $('#images img:first-child')[0];
            }
            current.className = '';
            next.className = 'active';

        },1000);
    };

    slide = start();

    var holder = $('#images')[0];

    holder.onmouseenter = function(){

        clearInterval(slide);

    }

    holder.onmouseleave = function(){
        slide = start();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing DOM and jQuery to select elements?

Comment: there in no jquery, it is my custom dom selector function

Comment: @MR.OK `$('#nav')` looks alot like jQuery to me. Or Zepto.

Comment: function $(id)
    {
        return document.querySelectorAll(id);
    }

Comment: I missed that, a lot of "personal" libraries copied the dollar sign and got screwed when they tried to adopt a library that uses it. So if there might be plans one day to use another larger library, you may want to change it. Just from personal experiences working with other companies.

Comment: @epascarello for this project i can't use javascript libraries, otherwise i use jQuery in my projects like http://zerzem.com/mrjquery, :D tnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have block scope, so all of the click handlers you create are referring to the same `image` variable.  You can create a scope by introducing a new function and calling it immediately:

```
var a = document.createElement('span');
a.onclick = (function(img){
    return function() {
        removeClass();
        img.className = 'active';
    };
})(image);
```

Or slightly cleaner, but you may need to shim `forEach` in oldIE:

```
var images = $('#images img'), nav = $("#nav")[0];
[].forEach.call(images, function(image){
    var a = document.createElement('span');
    a.onclick = function(){
        removeClass();
        image.className = 'active';
    }
    nav.appendChild(a);
});
```

Comment: ... but that’s not how you do it. Did you mean to return a function?

Answer (score -2):

You can restructure your code:

```
var $images = $('#images img').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $("<span>Text here</span>").on("click", function() {
        $images.removeClass("active");
        $this.addClass("active");
    }).appendTo("#nav");
});
```

Comment: javascript solution plz :|